# How to Hide Response Header inside Chrome Dev tools

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-devtools, response-headers

Is there any way to hide all the details inside the **Response Header** under Network Console under **Header** Section i tried finding a lot from internet but not getting related solution i tried finding in stack**overflow** but not getting.

Example

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With,Origin, remember-me,empID,Authorization,password ,username,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET,DELETE, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Content-Length: 28
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date: Wed, 11 Sep 2019 07:01:44 GMT
```

And i want also Hide inside the General Section Details For Eg:

```
Request URL: http://53.16.125.1:3030/vrc-1.1.2/getmenulist?roleId=31&productId=1
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 
Remote Address: 53.16.125.1:3030
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

This is java Code where i wrote this code

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;


    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET,DELETE, PUT");

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With,Origin, remember-me,empID,Authorization,password ,username,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

My **Expectation** is How to Hide all the details with the help of Coding

Thank In Advance

Happy Coding ☻

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (And remember their are other browsers with equivalent Dev Tools functionality.)

Comment: @Richard But i Want hide all the details used in my Backend and Frontend and it show's API name also any solution ..??

Comment: There is no way to do this. There are lots of options for users to see the detail of what is in the requests and responses (eg. local debugging proxies like Fiddler).  Remember the browser belongs to the user, not the web app.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to implement security through obscurity. This isn't going to work. You probably need authentication. Explain why you think you need this. You cannot hide what the browser does from the user, because the data **is** in the browser, in their network stack, in their memory and so on.

Comment: @Richard i Share my java Code any solution and also set parameter like empID,Authorization,password ,username, u can see inside the response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With,Origin, remember-me,empID,Authorization,password ,username,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Access-Control-Request-Method");

Comment: The entire content of the HTTP request and response is visible to anything operating at the HTTP level (application layer in the OSI model) is completely visible to tooling operating at that level. No code in any web app (including code running as part of a page in the browser) can change this.

Comment: that means it always will appear we can't do anything ☺